# Why click event is not propagating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attached a Header with a (kinda) close button (in red) moc-up. When I click on the close button (the area that overlaps with a header) - nothing happens. Can you please advice on the correct solution regarding the subject?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my_body" style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);padding:10px;"> 
    <div id="cls_btn" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;height:50px;width:50px;background-color:red;">  </div>
    <div id="my_header" style="position:relative;padding:14px 26px 26px">  </div> 
    <div id="pic_area" style="border:2px solid #b3b3b3;margin-top:10px">
        <img id="pic" src="http://never.mind.which.pic.com" >
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#cls_btn").bind("click", function() {
    alert("clicked!");

    return true;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JuGx9/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'my_header' cover it.
change the rows to:

```
<div id="my_header" style="position:relative;padding:14px 26px 26px">  </div> 
<div id="cls_btn" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;height:50px;width:50px;background-color:red;">  </div>
```

Comment: Why the line order matters please?

Comment: I mean, the *correct* elements order - will it be 100% portable across the browsers?

Comment: If you click in the top the event fire. When another div cover the button you dont click on the button but on the second div. so when I change the rows the button is above the second div and it can get your click. You can also move the 'my_header' to right in order it won't cover the button and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

This element (`<div id="my_header" style="position:relative;padding:14px 26px 26px">  </div>`) seems to be occupying the same space and is taking the click event, rather than the `#cls_btn` div. Applying a `z-index` CSS property with a value of `999` fixes the issue.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JuGx9/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to solve it without helping by a `z-index`. *Just curious*.

Answer (score 0):

The "my_header" div is overlapping the "cls_btn" div. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/JuGx9/13/

To solve this without the z-index property change the order of the divs...

http://jsfiddle.net/JuGx9/15/